# How to Automatic Filled Forms "Nama Lengkap" with User Full_Name in models Account and post it

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Im Confused, To Get Data User Login and post it in forms.
My question is how to do that ?

authentication/models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   email                   = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
   full_name               = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   create_account          = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_reviewer             = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   objects = CustomAccountManager()

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

   def __str__(self):
       return self.full_name
```

dashboard/models.py

```
class UserProfil(models.Model):
   jenis_kelamin_choice = (
       ('Pria', 'Pria'),
       ('Wanita', 'Wanita' ),
   )

    user                    = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    nik                     = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, unique=True)
    nidn                    = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, unique=True)
```

dashboard/forms.py

```
class UserProfilForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model           = UserProfil
    fields          = '__all__'

    widgets = {
        'user' : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 
                'namaLengkap', 'placeholder' : 'Nama Lengkap'}),
        'nidn' : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nidn', 
                 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Induk Dosen Nasional'}),
        'nik'  : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nik', 
                 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Induk Karyawan'}),
    }
```

dashboard/views.py

```
class UserProfilTemplateView(FormView):
    template_name       = 'dashboard/profil.html'
    form_class          = UserProfilForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user.full_name
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Data Profil Berhasil Disimpan.')
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I Want The Name User Is Appear in the Form "Nama Lengkap", How should i do ?

[image]

Profil.html.

Im call {{form.user}} but its not working. Can anyone help me? Thanks Before.

```
<form class="user">
        <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
            <h1 class="h5 mb-0 text-gray-800">Biodata Anggota Hibiner</h1>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-3 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                  <label for="gelarDepan">Gelar Depan</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="gelarDepan"
                      placeholder="First Name">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="namaLengkap">Nama Lengkap</label>
                  {{form.user}}
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="gelarBelakang">Gelar Belakang</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="gelarBelakang"
                      placeholder="Last Name">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                  <label for="nidn">NIDN</label>
                  {{form.nidn}}
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="nik">NIK</label>
                  {{form.nik}}
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                  <label for="emailInstitusi">Email Institusi</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="emailInstitusi"
                      placeholder="First Name">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="emailAlternatif">Email Alternatif</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="emailAlternatif"
                      placeholder="Last Name">
              </div>
          </div> </form>
```

Comment: Do you want to rename the placeholder, or prefill the form with certain information?

Comment: I want the form "Nama Lengkap" , filled data username login.

Comment: If your user is authenticated than you can get all info about logged in user from request like this ``{{request.user.full_name}}``

Comment: Where i put that code?

Comment: In your html template. <input value={{request.user.full_name}}/>t